# Close ssh connection from bash script

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi3

I want to turn my Raspberry Pi into a wireless access point (and back) with a bash script, which will be executed via ssh. Before leaving the current network I want to close the ssh connection from this script.

I already tried `pkill -f ssh -u pi`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `sudo`:)